# odoo onchange not get the data

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

on odoo i was try to onchange. The condition is, after i was insert the data like "SO00012", my code will try to browse the data by the insert code. here is my code :

```
 def onchange_data(self, cr, uid, vals, ids, context=None):

    stocks_picking_onchange = self.browse(cr, uid)
    products = []

    stiks = self.browse(cr, uid, ids)
    objk = self.pool.get('purchase.order')
    objeck = self.pool.get('data.stock.picking')
    objecks = objk.search(cr, uid,[('name','=',stiks.origin)])
    datas = objk.browse(cr, uid, objecks)

    if datas:
        for data in datas:
            for line in data.order_line:
                products.append((0, 0, {
                    'data1': line.id,
                    'data2' : line.product_qty,
                    'data3' : line.bonus,
                }))
```

But i was never get the data, My friend sugges me to add method create like :

```
def onchange_data(self, cr, uid, vals, ids, context=None):
    res =  super(stock_picking, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
    stocks_picking_onchange = self.browse(cr, uid)
    products = []
```

But, it's stil not working

Comment: I didn't see return statement in your *onchange()* method.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that you created the list of records but you didn't affect it to any field of your model:

```
if datas:
        products.append((5,0,false)) # if you want to remove all old records
        # i think without this line you will add the new record to the old list
        for data in datas:
            for line in data.order_line:
                products.append((0, 0, {
                    'data1': line.id,
                    'data2' : line.product_qty,
                    'data3' : line.bonus,
                }))
# return your value
return {'values' : {'your_field_name_here': products}}
```

one thing you should know with onchange data1, data2 and data3 must appear in the tree of  your field or web client will not know where to store them and they will be lost.